# Mocha Testing and Fixtures

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

What do fixtures look like using mocha (specifically with SailsJS)?

I've read through the docs here: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/testing

They explain every file and folder they use except fixtures. I'm hoping I can just create JSON files for all of my database objects and response objects. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in way how to handle fixtures. The mentioned folder `/tests/fixtures` in documentation is misleading. There are some packages to handle fixtures. [sails-hook-seed](https://github.com/lykmapipo/sails-hook-seed) and [sails-hook-fixtures](https://github.com/arryon/sails-hook-fixtures) seem to be the best maintained ones. Both having different formats to store the fixtures and suggest different places to put them.

Comment: It's particularly confusing that sails shows a /fixtures directory, but all the test examples I've seen handle fixtures in either /config or a test bootstrap file...

Comment: This book helps a bit. The text is obfuscated, but the examples are readable. https://livebook.manning.com/#!/book/sails-js-in-action/chapter-15/1